# Avoid circular dependency in header files in C

Tags: c, include, circular-dependency

I have two header files that refer to each other and that produce a compile error if I do not carefully put my includes on the right lines. Each of my header files matches with a srcs directory:

```c
___include
|____matrixes.h
|____define.h
|____transformations.h
|____tuples.h
|____pixels.h
|____ppm.h
|____Myproject.h
|____error_handler.h
|____graphics.h
```

Basically, Myproject.h contains all #include I needed, while every other header files contain prototypes, typedefs, structs, #defines I needed for the respective srcs directory. But I guess I got something wrong.
My problem comes from pixels.h, graphics.h and (maybe) Myproject.h. Here are they:

```c
#ifndef PIXELS_H
# define PIXELS_H

# include "Myproject.h"

typedef uint32_t t_pixel;
typedef unsigned char t_color;

//////////////////////////
//# include "graphics.h"
//////////////////////////

// pixels/conversions.c
t_tuple pixel_to_point(t_image image, int i, int j);
t_tuple point_to_pixel(t_image image, double x, double y);

// pixels/print.c
void    print_pixel(t_pixel p, char *name);

// pixels/pixels.c
t_pixel pixel(t_color r, t_color g, t_color b, t_color a);
t_color get_a(t_pixel pixel);
t_color get_r(t_pixel pixel);
t_color get_g(t_pixel pixel);
t_color get_b(t_pixel pixel);

// pixels/ops.c
t_pixel add_pixel(t_pixel p, t_pixel q);
t_pixel sub_pixel(t_pixel p, t_pixel q);
t_pixel scal_pixel(float q, t_pixel p);
t_pixel mul_pixel(t_pixel p, t_pixel q);

#endif
```

```c
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
# define GRAPHICS_H

# include "Myproject.h"

typedef struct s_window{
    void    *mlx;
    void    *win;
} t_window;

typedef struct s_image {
    void    *mlx;
    void    *img;
    char    *addr;
    int     bits_per_pixel;
    int     line_length;
    int     endian;
    t_tuple origin;
    t_tuple extension;
}   t_image;

typedef struct s_canvas{
    t_window    window;
    t_image     image;
} t_canvas;

// graphics/graphics.c
t_window    *window(t_window *cvs);
t_image *image(t_image *img, void *mlx);
t_canvas    *canvas(t_canvas *canvas);
void    put_pixel(t_image img, int x, int y, t_pixel pixel);

// graphics/free.c
void    free_window(t_window *window);
void    free_image(t_image *image);
void    free_canvas(t_canvas *canvas);

#endif
```

```c
#ifndef MYPROJECT_H
# define MYPROJECT_H

# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <limits.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <mlx.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include "libft.h"
# include "define.h"
# include "tuples.h"
# include "matrixes.h"
# include "pixels.h"
# include "graphics.h"
# include "ppm.h"
# include "error_handler.h"
# include "transformations.h"

#endif
```

As such, it did not compile with following error:

```
In file included from srcs/pixels/conversions.c:13:
In file included from include/miniRT.h:30:
include/pixels.h:22:24: error: unknown type name 't_image'
t_tuple pixel_to_point(t_image image, int i, int j);
                       ^
include/pixels.h:23:24: error: unknown type name 't_image'
t_tuple point_to_pixel(t_image image, double x, double y);
```

I understand the error because the pixel_to_point function takes a t_image as argument and in Myproject.h, graphics.h is included after pixels.h so it does not recognize the t_image type.
If I try to invert the graphics.h and pixels.h includes in Myproject.h, I just get the same error when a function from graphics.h needs the t_pixel type.
I can make it run by uncommenting the commented #include graphics.h in pixels.h (because it is AFTER the t_pixel typedef) but I feel it is an ugly method.

Is there a rule to follow to avoid these issues ?

Comment: Put all of your struct definitions and typedefs in one header, separate from function prototypes.

Comment: @dbush Is this how they do it in bigger programs ? Like creating a types.h header which contains all my structs and typedefs ?

Comment: Also include what only what you use in each header and c file, rather than putting all your includes for the whole project in one header and including it everywhere.

Comment: So I should delete Myproject.h and put the right includes in each header files. And then only include the respective header file in the matching srcs directory's files + create a general types.h header file? Is this some kind of a best practice ?

Comment: It's fairly common to have a project-wide header with common structures typdefs and so on, and to have individual header files for function declarations. 

But in your particular case, I wouldn't have pixels.h and graphics.h as separate at all; and they should only include the headers they *need*, not your project-wide header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your project include files to form some sort of hierarchy.

Have `pixel.h` only include `"tuples.h"`, etc.  What is needed, not `"Myproject.h"`.

Likewise for `"graphics.h"`.

---

Other strategies exist.

---

IMO, `typedef unsigned char t_color;` should not exist in `"pixels.h"`, but only in `"color.h"`.

IOWs, I recommend that each object/function/constant/macro declared in a `xyz.h` begin with a `xyz_` or the like.  OP's current approach has names spaces all over the place defined in a given `.h` file.  I see this as hard to follow and  unnecessarily difficult to maintain.

I would also recommend to rename functions like `add_pixel()` to `pixel_add()` to lead with the key-prefix *pixel*.

Comment: Thank you. I will delete my Myproject.h file and edit my code. 1. About the t_color typedef, you think I should create a color.h file just for that typedef ? 2. I get what you say about the xyz part and I like it so I will do so, but do you think this rule should be very strictly followed or no ? Like would you even rename the get_x functions to pixel_get_x or pixel_x or smt ? 3. What about the types.h file others mentioned above, do you think it is a good idea ?

Comment: @BobDeTunis `t_color` could be `pixel_color` in `pixel.h` .  Yes rename `get_x` functions to `pixel_get_x`. IMO, consider the  guts of your code as a library used by a higher level project and carve out your own name space:  `BDT.h`

Comment: I will do this, thank you. Why ```BDT.h``` though ?

Comment: BobDeTunis, BDT --> **B**ob**D**e**T**unis.  More distinctive than "MYPROJECT.h".  Use whatever makes sense for your project.

Comment: I get it lol.
I am currently editing my code. It is more tidy like this but I realized I still have my original issue: the ```t_image```type referred to in ```pixels.h``` cannot be found, and if I include ```graphics.h```inside ```pixels.h```, it won't find my ```t_pixel```type. Should I create a types.h file or just let my include after my ```t_pixel``` type declaration ?

Comment: @BobDeTunis Take a step back.  Do you really want `t_tuple pixel_to_point(t_image image, int i, int j);` and not `t_tuple pixel_to_point(t_image *image, int i, int j);`?  (note `*`).  Seems expensive to copy the whole `t_image`.  (Answer to this drives answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342348/avoid-circular-dependency-in-header-files-in-c/75342679?noredirect=1#comment132948507_75342679).)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251617/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-bobdetunis).